# In Orgmode, How to export (to pdf) box-drawing characters in src-block?

Tags: org-mode, org-export, latex, pdf

I just want to export my terminal TUI app's layout in src-block. Such as following:

```
* Heading

#+begin_src text
  ┌─────┐
  │     │
  └─────┘ ┌────────────┐┌────────────┐
  ┌─────┐ │            ││            │
  │     │ │            ││            │
  └─────┘ │            ││            │
  ┌─────┐ │            ││            │
  │     │ └────────────┘└────────────┘
  └─────┘
#+end_src
```

However, This doesn't export PDF file. and shows following error:

```
! LaTeX Error: Unicode character ┘ (U+2518)
               not set up for use with LaTeX.

See the LaTeX manual or LaTeX Companion for explanation.
Type  H <return>  for immediate help.
 ...                                              
                                                  
l.9 ...└────────────┘}
                                                  

! LaTeX Error: Unicode character └ (U+2514)
               not set up for use with LaTeX.

See the LaTeX manual or LaTeX Companion for explanation.
Type  H <return>  for immediate help.
 ...                                              
                                                  
l.9 ...└────────────┘}
                                                  
(That makes 100 errors; please try again.)
!  ==> Fatal error occurred, no output PDF file produced!
Transcript written on .//asdf.log.
```

- It seems it can't export box-drawing such as `└`, `┘`.
- How to make this work?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Oops, Just after @db48x's answer, I searched latex related forums, and found this [this question](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/281368/print-box-drawing-characters-with-pdflatex) in **tex-stackexchange**

Apparently adding following one line makes it work.

```
#+LATEX_HEADER: \usepackage{pmboxdraw}
```

Comment: You might also want to investigate the use of [ditaa](https://ditaa.sourceforge.net/) with Org mode.

Answer (score 0):

You need to go read the LaTeX documentation for the error message you are getting; this isn’t an Emacs or Org Mode problem.